# Subir un archivo al repositorio git pero que luego lo ignore

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

Quiero subir un proyecto a github en el hay un archivo llamado config.php quiero subirlo al repositorio pero una vez que este en la rama principal incluir este archivo en el gitignore para no modificarlo nunca mas. El problema es que si subo ese archivo al repositorio y posteriormente lo añado al gitignore el github desktop sigue incluyéndomelo en el commit. ¿Cómo hacer esta tarea de manera correcta?
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL  `.gitignore` no afecta los archivos a los que ya les estás haciendo tracking. La forma de indicarle a git que no le pare bolas a un archivo al que ya le estás haciendo tracking es a través de `git update-index`

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged el-archivo
```